# @RequestParam couldn't find CommonsMultipartFile attachFile[]

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am creating an email service using Spring 4 where the user can upload multiple attachments and the inputs come from a JSP page. I have implemented the service in the following way:

The JSP Page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Spring MVC - Email</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Spring MVC - Send e-mail with attachments</h1>

<form method="post" action="/sendEmail2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Email To:
    <input type="text" name="mailTo[]" size="65"/><br>

    CC:
    <input type="text" name="ccTo[]" size="65"/><br>

    Subject:
    <input type="text" name="subject" size="65"/><br>

    Message:
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="message"></textarea><br>

    From:
    <input type="text" name="from" size="65"/><br>

    Attach file:
    <input type="file" name="attachFile[]" size="60"/><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Send E-mail"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class myController2 {

    @Autowired
    ReportingService2 service2;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendEmail2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendEmail2(HttpServletRequest request,
                         @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile attachFile[]
) {
    String emailTo[] = request.getParameterValues("mailTo[]");
    String ccTo[] = request.getParameterValues("ccTo[]");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String msg = request.getParameter("message");
    fromName = request.getParameter("from");

    boolean res = service2.sendEmail(
            emailTo, ccTo, subject, msg, attachFile,
            fromName, username, password, hostName,
            encoding, protocol, portNo, TLS,
            sendPartial, SMTPAuth, SSL
    );


    if (res) {
        return "/WEB-INF/Result";

    } else {
        return "errorpage";
    }
}
```

The Service for email:

```
@Service
public class EmailService2 implements ReportingService2 {

    @Override
    public boolean sendEmail(String[] toEmailAddresses, String[] toCc,
                             String subject, String message,
                             CommonsMultipartFile[] attachFile,
                             String fromName, String userName,
                             String password, String hostName,
                             String encoding, String protocol,
                             String portNo, boolean TLS, boolean sendPartial,
                             boolean SMTPAuth, boolean SSL) {

        Properties mailProperties = new Properties();

        if (SSL) {
            // if SSL is used then port no should be 465
            mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
            mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", portNo);
            mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", false);

        } else if (TLS) {
            //if TLS is used then port no should be 587
            mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        }

        if (SMTPAuth) {
            mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        }

        if (sendPartial) {
            mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial", true);
        }

        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSenderImpl.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);

        //if no TLS and no SSL then default port no is 25
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPort(Integer.parseInt(portNo));
        javaMailSenderImpl.setHost(hostName);
        javaMailSenderImpl.setUsername(userName);
        javaMailSenderImpl.setPassword(password);
        javaMailSenderImpl.setDefaultEncoding(encoding);

        javaMailSenderImpl.send(mimeMessage -> {

            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, encoding);

            messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            messageHelper.setText(message);
            messageHelper.setFrom(fromName);

            if (toEmailAddresses != null) {
                for (String singleEmailTo : toEmailAddresses) {
                    messageHelper.setTo(singleEmailTo);
                }
            }

            if (toCc != null) {
                for (String singleCc : toCc) {
                    messageHelper.setCc(singleCc);
                }
            }

            if (attachFile != null) {
                for (CommonsMultipartFile singleFile : attachFile) {
                    messageHelper.addAttachment(singleFile.getOriginalFilename(), singleFile);
                }
            }
        });


        return true;
    }
}
```

Now when i run the project and hit the mapping the error i get is in the controller. Below is the error message:

```
**HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request**

**Type** Status Report

**Message** Required CommonsMultipartFile[] parameter 'attachFile' is not present

**Description** The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
```

I have tried to receive the array of attachments in the following way but it says incompatible type:

```
CommonsMultipartFile[] files=request.getParameterValues("attachFile[]");
```

Please help...

Comment: How r u hitting this mapping. Using some rest client like postman or using other code?

Comment: i am hitting via my JSP page. I have provided the implementation codes above.

Comment: In your controller user `@RequestParam("attachFile") ` And Can i Know why r u using CommonsMultipartFile. You can use MultipartFile instead. Also I think in your jsp it should be like this `name="attachFile"`. I dont know jsp. Just a guess

Comment: i am new to spring so i have gone through many implemntations. However your suggestion has worked and its working fine. i tried it as @RequestParam("attachFile[]") CommonsMultipartFile attachFile[].

Comment: if you post it as an answer then i could mark it as a solution.

Comment: Done. Cheers. Have a look. I feel you should switch to using MultipartFile. Check this out https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/

Comment: Would you please upvote my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller use

```
@RequestParam("attachFile")
```

As the error message says, spring framework is looking for a parameter with name 'attachFile'

Comment: @RequestParam("attachFile[ ]") worked out as i was sending an array from html.